# Equality of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$${S_{2n}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {\frac{1}{{{k^2}}} = } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{(2k)}^2}}} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{{(2k - 1)}^2}}}} } $$

I'm trying to figure out the explanation behind this equality.
Can you clarify it for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Write the sums out explicitly; you'll see what's going on...

Comment: OK, I added the two series on the righthand side and got:

$$\frac{{4{k^2} + 1}}{{16{k^4} - 16{k^3} + 4{k^2}}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
S_{2n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} \\[2mm]
       &= \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ \text{"k odd"}}}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} + \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ \text{"k even"}}}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} \\
       &= \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k=2p-1 \; (p \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast})}}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} + \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k=2p \; (p \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast})}}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{2}} \\[2mm]
       &= \sum_{p=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2p)^{2}} + \sum_{p=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2p-1)^{2}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Oh nice. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

The first sum on the righthand side regroups the terms for even $k$s, whereas the second sum regroups the odd $k$s. The subtle point here is justifying the convergence of the series and the notion of absolute convergence which allows rearrangement of terms.  Have you done that in class?

Comment: Someone down-voted your answer. Is there a reason for that? :)

Comment: @SuperStamp, perhaps the editor was worried that positive term series are necessarily absolutely convergent, and therefore my point might seem like a tautology.  However, even for positive-term series it needs to be justified that terms can be rearranged at will.  This property is what is usually understood by "absolute convergence", which is therefore nontrivial even for positive-term series.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you are working with partial sums rather than series, so my remarks on absolute convergence are only relevant for the next step in the argument.